# Uniqueness of Fourier Series Representation and the Fourier Transform of Periodic Signals

Tags: fourier-transform, continuous-signals, fourier, fourier-series

If we are given a signal of the form $$x(t) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty} a_k e^{j k \omega_0 t},$$ can we call it a Fourier Series representation of $x(t)$ right away?

Suppose we are given the signal $x(t) = e^{j2\Omega t} + e^{j4\Omega t}$, this signal can be expressed as $$x(t) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty} a_k e^{jk\Omega t},$$ however, in this case, $2\Omega$ is the fundamental frequency of the signal, not $\Omega$ as the equation above might suggest.

I ask this because in the second edition of Signals and Systems by Alan Oppenheim, he derives the Fourier transform of a periodic signal by considering the impulse train $$X(j\omega) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty} 2\pi a_k\delta (\omega - k \omega_0)$$
and applying the inverse Fourier transform to obtain $$x(t) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty} a_k e^{j k \omega_0 t},$$ which he says is the Fourier series representation of the signal without further discussion. But how do we know that in this case $\omega_0$ is the fundamental frequency of the signal? Couldn't it be the case that it is a signal of the form given above, namely, $x(t) = e^{j2\omega_0 t} + e^{j4\omega_0 t}$, in which case the fundamental frequenct is $2\omega_0$? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The Fourier series, if it exists, is unique, apart from the fact that we can always use a multiple of the fundamental period $T$ as the period, or, equivalently, a fraction of the fundamental frequency $\omega_0$. The only consequence of this is that we introduce Fourier coefficients with value zero in between the non-zero coefficients. The values of the non-zero coefficients remain unchanged:

$$x(t)=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_ke^{jk\omega_0}=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde{a}_ke^{jk\omega_0/N},\quad N\in\mathbb{Z}^+$$

$$\tilde{a}_k=\begin{cases}a_{k/N},\quad k=lN,\quad l\in\mathbb{Z}\\0,\quad\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Comment: So it **is** the Fourier series representation of $x(t)$ but there is no way for us to tell whether $a_k$ and $\omega_0$ represent the original coefficients and the **fundamental** frequency respectively beforehand?

Comment: i disagree with your very first statement, @MattL.: *"The Fourier series, if it exists, is unique,..."*  $$ $$ of course that's not true.  you can always bump $\omega_0$ to $1/N$ of its previous value (where $N \in \mathbb{Z}$) call that your **new** $\omega_0$ and fill in zeroes for the $N-1$ intermediate terms between the potentially non-zero coefficients spaced every $N$ terms.  i know you're saying essentially this also, but it contradicts your opening premise.

Comment: of course if $$ x(t+T) = x(t) \qquad \qquad \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R} $$, then it is also always true that $$ x(t+2T) = x(t) \qquad \qquad \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R} $$ or $$ x(t+NT) = x(t) \qquad \qquad \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R}, \ N \in \mathbb{Z} $$  and **sometimes** it's true that $$ x(t+\tfrac12 T) = x(t) \qquad \qquad \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R} $$ or $$ x(t+\tfrac1N T) = x(t) \qquad \qquad \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R}, \ N \in \mathbb{Z}  $$ but if it's **not** true for any submultiples of $T$, **then** you have a unique Fourier series.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: well, that's what I say in the following clause of my first sentence, but since that is quite trivial I didn't want to say that it's NOT unique, because using a multiple of $T$ as the period just changes the *index* of the coefficients, not the coefficients themselves, and that's a triviality.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: I'll reformulate to make this entirely clear ...

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: And note that I said "the Fourier **series** is unique", which is indeed true, because the series is always the same. The index of the coefficients might be different, but if you write the sum explicitly, you'll *always* end up with the same expression (because of the zero coefficients).

Comment: i think you have to say that $T$ is the smallest possible value of $T>0$ such that $$ x(t+T)=x(t) \qquad \qquad \forall \ t \in \mathbb{R}$$ to say that the resulting Fourier series is unique.  (BTW, i can't edit my previous longer comment, but the "$\forall ... N \in \mathbb{Z}$" on the last line is not correct.)

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Check again my previous comment, the *series* itself is always unique, no matter how I represent it (with or without zero coefficients in between the non-zero coefficients). The non-zero contributions to the sum remain the same. It's just like $1+2+3=1+0+2+0+3+0$. It would be different if two really different sets of coefficients converged to the same function, but that's not the case. That would be a case of non-uniqueness.

Comment: i agree with the meaning of what you said with $$1+2+3...=1+0+2+0+3+0...$$.  but i disagree that the series expression is unique when that expression is $$ x(t) = \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} c_n e^{j n \omega_0 t}  $$

Comment: @MattL. But do you agree that it is not true that $\omega_0$ being the fundamental frequency does not imply that two consecutive values of the coefficients are nonzero? Take for instance $x(t) = e^{j\omega t} + e^{j 5\omega t}$

Comment: @0MW: Yes, that's indeed a sufficient condition, but it's not necessary.